azure managed grafana not working with azure private resources
We are using azure sql vm internally in private network and azure managed grafana on private endpoint. We would like to display data from sql to azure managed grafana. We observed that the connection works only if the sql vm is on public network.
How can we access private azure sql from azure managed grafana?
Do we need to setup both azure sql and azure managed grafana on public network? Or can we connect both with private network and private IPs?
We have setup diagnostics, but we are also unable to see server logs. It would be helpful if someone help with getting server logs as well.
We tried setting up azure sql on private VNET and adding private IP of sql to azure managed grafana data source, but getting error as "failed to connect to server". Also we were not able to see any server logs.
But when we setup azure sql on public network, we were successfully able to add sql data source with public IP on azure managed grafana.
Could anyone please guide on how to add private IPs to azure managed grafana and also how to check server logs


azure managed grafana not working with azure private resources

If you are trying to access Azure SQL from Azure Managed Grafana with private access, check the following configurations.
Create a Grafana instance with a private endpoint. If it has already been created, please check the DNS configuration and virtual link settings.

Grafana Private DNZ zone configuration

Virtual Link configuration

Create a SQL VM in the same VNet. After creating the SQL VM, ensure you create an NSG rule to allow the necessary ports.

After completing all the configurations, Grafana will be able to access the SQL VM.

Refer the Stack Link related to same kind of issue.
Connect to a data source privately
